# Range of floating point numbers in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

Excerpt from a book:

> A float value consists of a 24-bit
>   signed mantissa and an 8-bit signed 
>       exponent. The precision is approximately seven decimal digits.
>   Values 
>       range from 
>       -3.402823 × 10^38 to 3.402823 × 10^38

How to calculate this range?  Can someone explain the binary arithmetic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely read the article to which Richard points.  But if you need a simpler explanation, I hope this helps:

Basically, as you said, there is 1 sign bit, 8 bits for exponent, and 23 for fraction.
Then, using this equation (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision))

`N = (1 - 2s) * 2^(x-127) * (1 + m*2^-23)`

where `s` is the sign bit, `x` is the exponent (minus the 127 bias), and `m` is the fractional part treated as a whole number (the equation above transforms the whole number into the appropriate fraction value).

Note, that the exponent value of `0xFF` is reserved to represent infinity.  So the largest exponent of a real value is `0xFE`.

you see that the maximum value is

`N = (1 - 2*0) * 2^(254-127) * (1 + (2^23 - 1) * 2^-23)`

`N = 1 * 2^127 * 1.999999`

`N = 3.4 x 10^34`

The minimum value would be the same but with the sign bit set, which would simply negate the value to give you `-3.4 X 10^34`.

[Q.E.D.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.)

Answer (score 7):

You need to read ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) which will explain how floating point numbers are stored, which will also answer your question.

Comment: Just adding to the list of articles: [Floating Point in .NET](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/resources/Articles/FPDotNetConceptsAndFormats.aspx)

Comment: Also a video series for calculating IEEE 754 Floating Point Format: [Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owtK58XiPGo) and [Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H79PNQ4Z9HE)