# How the float type range is calculated (±1.5 * E−45 to ±3.4 * E+38)?

Tags: c#

[Floating-point numeric types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types)

Says "Approximate range" for `float` is ±1.5 x 10−45 to ±3.4 x 1038.

Why the negative exponent **(-45)** not (-38) ? and where 1.5 and 3.4 come from?

for the float type there are 8 bits for the exponent 1 bit for the sign and 23 significant bits 2^8 =256, log(2^256) = 77, 77/2=38.5 so the lowest non zero value should be 10^-38 not 10^-45

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types

Comment: That's an awkward definition of "range"... Clearly whoever wrote the article wanted to say "smallest representable non-zero value and largest representable non-infinity number" but shortened it to a "range" which is not range...

Comment: 1.5 x 10^-45 isn't wrong, that's the smallest non-zero number, but a denormal. If you take the smallest *normalized* number, then it would be 1.1755 x 10^-38

Comment: (Side note: answers will likely have to rehash usual https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334353/range-of-floating-point-numbers-in-net so consider if you want to just stick with it as duplicate)

Comment: Thank you,
for the float type there are 8 bits for the exponent 1 bit for the sign and 23 significant bits 2^8 =256, log(2^256) = 10^77, 77/2=38.5 so the lowest non zero value should be 10^-38 not 10^-45

Comment: @Vector yes, but you have not considered denormals in that calculation. E: you can check the example on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Single-precision_examples)

Comment: @harold Thanks a lot this is exactly what am looking for much appreciated.